# JQuery on click link with href atribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code structure. Its a set of wordpress tabs. I have many tabs all over the website, using Jquery i want to trigger a function when a user clicks one of the links, however i cant apply a ID atribute so my funtion below doesnt work...any suggestions?

JQUERY

```
$('#1485856532455-70ee0dfe').on('click', function() {
$('.otherdiv').css('background-image', 'url(http://placehold.it/200x200/ff0000)');
})
```

HTML

```
<ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
<li class="vc_tta-tab">
<a href="#1485856532455-70ee0dfe"> <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Title</span></a>
</li>

<li class="vc_tta-tab">
<a href="#1485856532489"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Title</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

You can't select them by ID because they don't have IDs. But you can use [**CSS Atrribute-Equal Selector**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp) to get them by `href` attribute. Like this:

```
$('[href="#1485856532455-70ee0dfe"]').on('click', function() {
    // ...
}
```

More CSS Selectors [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

**Working code snippet:**

```js
$('[href = "#1485856532455-70ee0dfe"]').click(function() {
  alert("#1485856532455-70ee0dfe was clicked! Hoooray!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#1485856532455-70ee0dfe"> <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Title</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="vc_tta-tab">
    <a href="#1485856532489"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Title</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @user1673498 what do you mean by not working? Do you mean it still scroll down to the anchor?

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute selector then :

```
$('[href="#1485856532455-70ee0dfe"]').on('click', function() {....});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#1485856532455-70ee0dfe').on('click', function() {` - means that on page we have some element with id 1485856532455-70ee0dfe. In your html code no id with text 1485856532455-70ee0dfe, thats why your code not work.

You have two case to fix:

1. add id's to needed element
2. change js to `$('[href="1485856532455-70ee0dfe"]').on('click', function() {`

Answer (score 0):

You cant give a id to a link like that. However you can select the  link with jquery by doing $('[href="#1485856532455-70ee0dfe"]').on('click', function() {....});